# For Loop in Shell Script - add breakline in csv file

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, sh

I'm trying to use a `for` loop in a shell script.

I am executing a command from a text file. I wish to execute each command 10 times and insert some stats into a csv file. After that command has been done, I want to start the next BUT put a line break in the CSV file after the first command that was done 10 times.

Is the following correct:

```
#Function processLine
processLine(){
line="$@"
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
START=$(date +%s.%N)
echo "$line"
eval $line > /dev/null 2>&1

END=$(date +%s.%N)
DIFF=$(echo "$END - $START" | bc)

echo "$line, $START, $END, $DIFF" >> file.csv 2>&1
echo "It took $DIFF seconds"
echo $line
done
}
```

Thanks all for any help

### UPDATE

It is doing the loop correctly, but I can't get it to add a line break after each command is executed 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
processLine()
{
    line="$@"

    echo $line >> test_file
    for ((i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++))
    do
        # do not move to the next line
        echo -n "$i," >> test_file
    done

    # move to the next line: add the break
    echo >> test_file
}

echo -n > test_file

processLine 'ls'
processLine 'find . -name "*"'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks reasonable.  Does it do what you want it to?

You could simplify some things, e.g.

```
DIFF=$(echo "$END - $START" | bc)
```

could be just

```
DIFF=$((END - START))
```

if END and START are integers, and there's no need to put things in variables if you're only going to use them once.

If it's *not* doing what you want, edit the question to describe the problem (what you see it doing and what you'd rather have it do).

Comment: Note that $END en $START contain reals. This means $(()) won't work, right?

Answer (score 0):

How about just adding a line "`echo >> file.csv`" after `done`? Or do you only want an empty line between each block of 10? Then you could do the following:

```
FIRST=1
processline()
{
  if (( FIRST )) then
    FIRST = 0
  else
    echo >> file.csv
  fi
  ...rest of code...
}
```

Otherwise you might want to give an example of the desired output and the output you are getting now.